# enable adb via adb sideload

Tags: android, adb, sideloading

Following scenario:
I have a unrooted (stock) android phone (Samsung) and I need to enable adb, but I don't have access to the device (forgot the lock code).

Is it possible to enable adb debugging via adb sideload from recovery?

For example creating a update.zip, that enables adb or installs an app, that enables adb on boot?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

> Is it possible to enable adb debugging via adb sideload from recovery?

No. Your app would need special permissions to do such a thing. Obviously if an arbitrary app was able to turn on adb debugging without asking the user that'd be a bad thing.

As a side note, this sounds like what someone would ask if they had acquired a phone that didn't belong to them. Not that this would change the validity of my answer.